# can I set a filter in an alias physical table in the repository

Tags: obiee

I am using OBI 11g and in the repository I have a table `translations_us`. In this table I have 3 columns: `category, ID, translation`

this table is used for different translations of different categories.

For example I want the translation of the postal_code, then I have to take

```
select * from translation_us where category='postal_code'
```

If I want the translation of manager_code, Then it is

```
 select * from translation_us where category='manager_code'
```

In the repository I want to make aliases of the table `translation_us`, but I want to put in the physical layer a filter on that alias. Is that possible?

Comment: Bigjo did you give up or did the response help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter would not go into the physical layer. It would go into the WHERE clause of the Logical Table Source for the logical dimension (or fact depending on how you use it).